# Как заполнить radiobutton массивом C# Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть несколько radioButton пример,  (заполнены для примера, нужно случайными через цикл.)

```
`radioButton1.Text = tx1[0];
radioButton2.Text = tx1[1];
radioButton3.Text = tx1[2];
radioButton4.Text = tx1[3];
radioButton5.Text = tx1[4];`
```

Сам массив, который получается перемешенный

```
Random rnd = new Random();

        List<string> t1 = tx1.ToList<string>();
        List<string> s1 = new List<string>();




        while (t1.Count != 0)
        {
            string temp = t1[rnd.Next(0, t1.Count - 1)];
            t1.Remove(temp);
            s1.Add(temp);
        }


        string[] dd = s1.ToArray<string>();
```

Как заполнить значением из string[] dd1 чтобы были разные значения для каждого radioobutton? Заранее спасибо.

(Для тех кто делать будет не забудьте кнопку в rdbList добавить, rdbList.Add(Название кнопки на форме);))

Comment: Так получается, что сейчас у каждой кнопки, разные значения массивов. Наверное вы что-то другое хотите?

Comment: Да это для примера вывел, а мне нужно чтобы случайными значениями заполнялось, пробовал делать цикл заполняя список radiobutton и передав значение, не получилось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот на скорую руку придумал такое решение:

Имеется исходный массив `str`, делаем из него другой, с которым будем работать (вдруг исходный пригодиться для чего-либо) - `newStr`. Также имеется список кнопок `rdbList`

Будем проходить по циклу и генерировать случайное число, причём максимально возможное число определяется количеством слов в рабочем массиве. Затем по полученному числу вытаскиваем слово из массива, передаём его в `Text` кнопки.

Потом, чтобы слова в кнопках не повторялись, создаём новый список на основе рабочего массива, удаляем из него использованное слово и кладём в рабочий массив, новый массив, без этого слова:

```
      private void Test()
      {
         string[] str = { "1", "2", "3" };//исходный массив
         string[] newStr = str.ToArray<string>();//рабочий массив
         List<RadioButton> rdbList = new List<RadioButton>(); //список с кнопками

         Random rnd = new Random();
         int num;
         for(int i=0; i<newStr.Length;i++)
         {
            num = rnd.Next(newStr.Length);//случайное число
            rdbList[i].Text = newStr[num];//слово в текст кнопки

            List<string> lst = new List<string>(newStr);
            lst.RemoveAt(num);//удаляем использованное слово
            newStr = lst.ToArray();//массив без использованного слова
         }
      }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло)